# how to change MongoDB output JSON format

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDb and would appreciate some help with this query. I wrote the following aggregation pipeline

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "type" : "L" }},
    { "$facet": {
        "ON": [
            { "$match" : {"lampStatus":'ON'}},
            { "$count": "ON" }
        ],
        "OFF": [
            { "$match" : {"lampStatus": 'OFF'}},
            { "$count": "OFF" }
        ]
    } },
    { "$project": {
        "ON": { "$ifNull": [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$ON.ON", 0] }, 0 ] },
        "OFF": { "$ifNull": [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$OFF.OFF", 0] }, 0 ] },
    } }
])
```

and got output of this type

```
{
    "ON" : 0.0,
    "OFF": 30
}
```

but how to get this type of output with json format

```
/* 1 */ 
{ 
    "_id": "ON", 
    "count" : 0.0 
} 

/* 2 */ 
{ 
    "_id": "OFF", 
    "count" : 30.0 
}
```

any one please suggest me?

**Actual Output**

```
{
    "ON" : 0.0,
    "OFF" : 30
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
{
    "_id" : "ON",
    "COUNT" : 0.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "OFF",
    "COUNT" : 30.0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need some more aggregation trick

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "type" : "L" }},
  { "$facet": {
    "ON": [{ "$match" : {"lampStatus": "ON" }}, { "$count": "ON" }],
    "OFF": [{ "$match" : {"lampStatus": "OFF" }}, { "$count": "OFF" }]
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "ON": { "$ifNull": [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$ON.ON", 0] }, 0 ] },
    "OFF": { "$ifNull": [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$OFF.OFF", 0] }, 0 ] },
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "data": {
      "$map": { "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" }, "in": { "_id": "$$this.k", "count": "$$this.v" }}
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$data" }}
])
```

Comment: Got it Thank you so much @ Anthony Winzlet

Answer (score 1):

**Upodated**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "type" : "L" }},
    { "$facet": {
        "ON": [
            { "$match" : {"lampStatus":'ON'}},
            { "$count": "ON" }
        ],
        "OFF": [
            { "$match" : {"lampStatus": 'OFF'}},
            { "$count": "OFF" }
        ]
    } },
    {"$project": { 
            myArray: [ 
                {_id:"ON", count: { "$ifNull": [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$ON.ON", 0] }, 0 ]} },
                {_id:"OFF", count: { "$ifNull": [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$OFF.OFF", 0] }, 0 ] }}
        ] 
        }},

        {"$unwind":"$myArray"},

        {
            "$replaceRoot": { newRoot: "$myArray" }
        }

])
```

Comment: Iam try this code Iam not getting exact result iam getting this type result like{
    "_id" : "ON",
    "myArray" : [ 
        0.0, 
        0.0
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "OFF",
    "myArray" : [ 
        0.0, 
        0.0
    ]
} @abdul

Comment: @what about now?

Comment: i am trying this { $group: { "_id": "$lampStatus",COUNT: { $sum:1} } },i am getting json exact result but small isssue lampstatus:"ON" there are no records so not getting {
        "_id" : "ON",
        "COUNT" : 0.0
    },value

Comment: @NareshVarunGuttula updated my answer,  it's an alternative solution.

Comment: Thank you so much @abdul